# How does gboard app work in iOS?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

The gboard app available within app store for ios provides a custom keyboard that can be used to provide inputs to any text based application and runs smoothly with iMessages , messenger, whatsapp etc. It also provides advanced features like google contextual search within the keyboard that can be pasted across.

From an ios app development perspective, how does this work with other applications  since iOS app development , cocoa touch architecture enforces application sandboxing where inter app communication is restricted. One can communicate only using url schemes or icloud, that too in a limited extent.

So how has been this application developed and which advanced features of cocoa touch has been utilised to develop such an app

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with a specific programming language. Adding those tags adds no value to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it is a keyboard extension. Apple added this ability in iOS 8.

It is fully documented in the [Custom Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html) section of the [App Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH20-SW1).